# Header image over section title

Tags: graphics, koma-script, chapters

I'm usinge the koma class srcbook for which I have defined a custom chapter style:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\definecolor{myblue}{RGB}{26,33,137}

\addtokomafont{disposition}{\usefont{T1}{cmbr}{b}{n}\selectfont\color{myblue}}
\addtokomafont{chapter}{\fontsize{25pt}{25pt}\selectfont}
\newkomafont{chapternumber}{\fontsize{40}{100}\selectfont\color{white}}
\newkomafont{chaptername}{\footnotesize\color{white}}

\renewcommand\chapterformat{%
    \raisebox{-6pt}{\colorbox{myblue}{%
        \parbox[b][50pt]{40pt}{\centering%
            \vspace{2pt}
            {\usekomafont{chaptername}{\chaptername}}%
            \vfill{\usekomafont{chapternumber}{\thechapter\autodot}}%
            \vspace{6pt}%
}}}\enskip}

\begin{document}
    \chapter{My chapter}
    \blindtext
\end{document}
```

I would like to put a header above the actual section title, showing some graphic related to the chapter topic (i.e. it would be different for each chapter and just optional).

It could be quite simple, like `\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{myheader.pdf}`, but I was not able to find any way to place the image just above the chapter title.

Thank you for any advice!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Answer (score 2):

I don't know `scrbook`, so maybe there is another solution.

But with `epigraph` package it's quite simple, you have only to adjust the dimensions and positions according to your actual image.

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{epigraph}
\setlength{\epigraphwidth}{\textwidth}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\definecolor{myblue}{RGB}{26,33,137}

\addtokomafont{disposition}{\usefont{T1}{cmbr}{b}{n}\selectfont\color{myblue}}
\addtokomafont{chapter}{\fontsize{25pt}{25pt}\selectfont}
\newkomafont{chapternumber}{\fontsize{40}{100}\selectfont\color{white}}
\newkomafont{chaptername}{\footnotesize\color{white}}

\renewcommand\chapterformat{%
    \raisebox{-6pt}{\colorbox{myblue}{%
        \parbox[b][50pt]{40pt}{\centering%
            \vspace{2pt}
            {\usekomafont{chaptername}{\chaptername}}%
            \vfill{\usekomafont{chapternumber}{\thechapter\autodot}}%
            \vspace{6pt}%
}}}\enskip}

\renewcommand\chapterheadstartvskip{%
  \vspace*{4cm}}

\begin{document}
    \chapter{My chapter}\epigraphhead[1cm]{\includegraphics[width=\textwidth, height=5cm]{example-image-duck}}
    \blindtext
    \chapter{Another chapter}\epigraphhead[1cm]{\includegraphics[width=\textwidth, height=5cm]{example-image}}
    \blindtext
\end{document}
```

[image]